# Docker variable in choco command

Tags: docker, powershell

I have a docker run command that runs a chocolatey command. I am trying to use a variable in the choco command but getting an error. Hard coding the value of the variable in the command works.

This fails:

```
ARG azurecli_version="2.43.0"
RUN powershell choco feature enable -n allowGlobalConfirmation; choco install azure-cli --version ${azurecli_version} --no-progress
```

Error:

```
'--no-progress' is not a valid version string.
```

This works:

```
RUN powershell choco feature enable -n allowGlobalConfirmation; choco install azure-cli --version 2.43.0 --no-progress
```

Comment: Where did you define the `azurecli_version` variable?

Comment: It's at the start of my docker file just below the image we pull.

Comment: This would be a Docker issue and not a Chocolatey one as its variable substitution inside a Docker file. Have you looked at https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/?